# How to move dialog boxes using win32 API?

Tags: c, winapi, win32gui

I want to make the dialog box bounce around the screen like the dvd bouncing logo, tried searching online but noone seems to have brought this up. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you looking for the SetWindowPos function?

Comment: Possibly use a timer and in the `OnTimer` handler use `SetWindowPos` or `MoveWindow`.